# Entity Framework 4 Cascade update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Does EF4 support Cascade update rule? Does it make sence like with Cascade delete rule or is it automatic that all gets updated when i call SaveChanges on my context? I could see that there is Cascade update option in MSSQL 2005 but i dont seem to find the support for it in EF4...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Entity Framework Support Cascade Update, you can see this property in .edmx file on Property Tab when you click on Table Associations

Comment: Well that is awkward, I dont see it there. I see only OnDelete rule. If I set it up in database its not generated (only onDelete is). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to Update Entity Key in EF, even if it is a part of composite one. Therefore, EF doesn't allow you to create an association without Entity Key. You can provide this only on database layer.